# Ajax requested file does not appear on the Network tab (Firefox debugging tool )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to add a username validator to my website to run when the form is submitted , check if the username and password true then redirect to the next page .

The first step i did is a function which take the username and password parameter then create the **XMLhttpRequest** and open the 'login.php' file then check if the password is correct or not.

For debugging propose I added an alert to inform me when the ready state is 4 and the status is 200 .

This is my code :

```
function checkuser(user,input){
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
       alert('works !');
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/public/login.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But when i submit the button and run the function i get only the alert and when i check my Network tab in Firefox debugging tools i don't see any new file added to the requests .

Comment: Uhm what, you're getting the alert, so it clearly works, but what are you expecting to see, added to the request how ?

Comment: The login.php file contains only <?php print('Works'); ?>  so i am expecting in the network tab a new file login.php which contain a Works paragraph

Comment: I was doubting if the directory is wrong so i there any way to validate the directory , I tried setting a variable to the open method and alert(nameofvar); but i had a blank alert no boolean was appearing (true or false)